# How to turn on tab completion in zsh/prezto?

Tags: osx, zsh

I have installed `prezto` and trying out `zsh`.

However tab completion is not on by default.

What is the best way to enable tab completion in prezto?

Comment: From the README.md: "Load the modules you need in ~/.zpreztorc then open a new Zsh terminal window or tab." It seems to be [enabled by default](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/blob/master/runcoms/zpreztorc)...

Comment: It is not working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning I had set my default shell to

```
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/zsh
```

This shell is installed by brew.

Obviously tab completion does not work in this shell.

After I switched to the default system zsh in osx,

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

Tab completion works.